# Grothendieck construction over a monoidal base

Tags: ct.category-theory

Lately I got interested in this kind of variation/specialization of the Grothendieck construction. Whatever piece of literature that might be relevant is welcome!

Let $C$ be a category and $[C,C]$ its endofunctor category (solve possible size issues the way you prefer).

1. Discrete fibrations over $[C,C]$ correspond to presheaves on $[C,C]$ using the usual construction of elements/fibers of a fibration. What if, now, a discrete fibration $p : E \to [C,C]$ is also a monoidal functor, i.e. what if $E$ is monoidal and "acts on $C$"? What special property/ies inherits the associated presheaf?
2. On the same assumption on $p$, what does the associated presheaf $\sigma_p : [C,C]\to Set$ do to monads on $C$?

Same question, but now $p$ is not a discrete fibration anymore; instead, it is a generic monoidal functor $E \to [C,C]$ witnessing an action of $E$ on $C$. Then, $p$ [still corresponds](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/displayed+category) to some map out of $[C,C]$, and precisely to a *normal lax functor*
$$
\sigma_p : [C,C] \to Prof
$$ to the bicategory of profunctors. What special property of $\sigma_p$ is induced by the fact that $p$ is strong monoidal?

Comment: It seems to be a bit more specific than what you describe, but [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00727) has almost the same title as your question, so maybe it could be useful.

Comment: I think that, Given $V$ a (small) monoidal category and a discrete fibration $E \rightarrow V$ corresponding to presheaf $F$ over $V$, then a monoidal structure on $E$ making the functor monoidal is essentially the same as a monoid structure on $F$ for the closed tensor product on $Psh(V)$ generated from the one on $V$.